# Image overlay help - it all stacks over one image

Tags: html, css, overlay, positioning

I have a set of four images, and my functionality goal is so that when you hover the mouse over the image thumbnail, it applies an overlay with some information that you can click.

To give you an idea, take a look at this image:

[image]

I've got the basics down, but currently the overlays are just stacking in the top left image. Not sure how to fix it, so I wondered if you guys could help.

Here's the website:
http://lab.albionmedia.biz/clients/silverdale/

Have a look at my code and see what you think!

Comment: I dont know how yours current code looks like, but you should play around onMouseOver and onMouseOut events and add / remove css class that will be response for showing extra content ( invisible / disabled by default)

Comment: not sure you've explained yourself clearly. you want each thumbnail in the set of 4 to have the overlay appear on top of it on hover? Do you want to do this with CSS only or with jQuery, which you've already loaded?

Comment: I was hoping to do it with CSS, then let jQuery take care of the rollover stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div's are now block elements, and they have no height because they are filled by floats/absolute positioned elements.

Change:

```
#columns .column .image {
   position:relative;
 width:100%;
}
```

To:

```
#columns .column .image {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
```

And you should get something much closer to what you want. It might need some tweaking after this.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for your help! Needs tweaking like you said, but it's all sorted now.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did! I just need to do the jQuery bit now

Answer (score 1):

without touching the CSS, you could get jQuery to do everything for you.

```
$('.overlay').fadeTo(0,0); //hide the images to start with
$('.image').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.overlay').fadeTo(200,1)},
    function(){
        $(this).children('.overlay').fadeTo(200,0)}
);
```

Comment: This works really nicely, thanks for your help buddy, keep it up